# Units for stock indexes

Tags: word-choice, counters

When reading Japanese financial news, I found that different units were used for different stock indexes. [For example](https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/79084), ドル／セント was used for Dow Jones Industrial Average, while ポイント was used for NASDAQ Composite. (Emphasis mine)

> 結局、**ダウ工業株30種平均**の終値は、前の日より、**161ドル60セント**高い、**2万8,653ドル87セント**と続伸し[...]
>
> 一方、ハイテク株主体の**ナスダック総合指数**は反発し、**70.29ポイント**上がって、1万1,695.63と[...]

Why are different units used to describe the different indexes? Why is Dow described in dollar, and NASDAQ in point?

This is different from English's terminology, where [point was used for Dow](https://www.thestreet.com/markets/stock-market-dow-jones-industrial-average-federal-reserve-082820).

My initial guess is that the weighing method has something to do with the units used. Dow is [price-weighed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price-weighted_index) where NASDAQ is [market cap-weighed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization-weighted_index). But I could not work out how this leads to different units being used.

Comment: the Japanese is following the convention used in the US.   this doesn’t seem to really be a question for this particular forum. you should perhaps ask this on a marketing forum.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average#Calculation): "To calculate the DJIA, the sum of the prices of all 30 stocks is divided by a divisor, the Dow Divisor ... Early on, the initial divisor was composed of the original number of component companies; this initially made the DJIA a simple arithmetic average."

Comment: @A.Ellet, in what sense is the Japanese "following the convention used in the U.S."? In the U.S. we might say "the Dow was up 287 points," or "the Dow was up 1%," but I don't think I've ever heard anyone say something like "the Dow was up 287 dollars." (And of course, 287 points on the Dow does not represent $287 in value.)

Comment: @A.Ellett I considered posting to Money.SE instead of Japanese. I picked here because it is easier to get a financial expert here than to get a Japanese expert there.

Comment: @Nanigashi Good point on English's use of point for Dow. I will add that into my question.

Comment: So I did a little digging into this. It's pretty weird. From what I can find, most foreign indices are in points except the Dow Jones. The Nikkei is in yen, but the TOPIX is in points as well. I wonder if it's simply based on when the index was created/translated?

Comment: I'd bet @Ringil is right. As broccoli face - mask cloth points out above, the Dow was originally a simple arithmetic average of stock prices, so the Dow on any given day would have been the average share price of the stocks included in the index, in dollars. At the time, people probably **did** say "the Dow reached x dollars today," or "the Dow fell by $1.45"; that would have been perfectly logical. Use of ドル for the Dow probably dates to this early period, and simply wasn't changed later when the introduction of a Dow divisor other than 1 necessitated a change in English terminology.